# An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0. Camera does not exist. Nexus5X

Tags: android, android-camera, nexus-5

I brought a Nexus5X few days ago. I tried to test an android app on it. It keeps reporting error:

`W/CameraBase﹕ An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
 D/TAG﹕ Camera Does Not exist`

I print out the Camera numbers by `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()`, it says `2`. 
I also tried to do `Camera.open(1)`, same thing:

```
W/CameraBase﹕ An error occurred while connecting to camera: 1
D/TAG﹕ Camera Does Not exist
```

I ran this app on other phones like Nexus 4, it works fine. 
Any idea how to deal with this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It is Nexus 5X. I cannot find the correct tag.

Comment: Have you declared `uses-feature Camera` on the Manifest?

Comment: Have you added the necessary permission?

Comment: ... and Nexus 5x runs Android 6.0. Have you checked the runtime permissions?

Comment: I did write: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/> in AndroidManifest

Comment: Problem Solved! Thank you reidzeibel and Christopher. The problem is I have to go to Setting->App->MY_APP to add Camera to its permission. :)